# How to use docker build caching properly with remote registry image?

Tags: docker, caching, devops

I'm trying to implement caching into my CI/CD process to make docker image building faster. I've the pervious built image and I want to use it during the building process. For every CI/CD job we have a clean building environment.

For testing I've made a pretty simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as base
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096"
COPY package*.json ./
```

For building the CI/CD doing the steps below:

```
docker image pull node:16-alpine
docker image pull registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
docker image build -t cache_test:latest --cache-from=node:16-alpine,registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest .
```

After running it I got this output:

```
16-alpine: Pulling from library/node
59bf1c3509f3: Already exists 
683dd8c3cc08: Pull complete 
ae5b2724f19b: Pull complete 
39190df3f477: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2c6c59cf4d34d4f937ddfcf33bab9d8bbad8658d1b9de7b97622566a52167f2b
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:16-alpine
docker.io/library/node:16-alpine
latest: Pulling from klmos/test
59bf1c3509f3: Already exists 
683dd8c3cc08: Already exists 
ae5b2724f19b: Already exists 
39190df3f477: Already exists 
a69f3fec5d45: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bd53593d3c15720b49f6228a6e027b8b6b3396edac19683ec5ad5f4ef913b44e
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
[+] Building 0.6s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 131B                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 1.90MB                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:6052ed21a28aff3483d52a6b72ecc3237ce70cfb74f5bc8d467827a16fdf09cc                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/cache_test:latest
```

If I run it twice in the same job on the second run I can see the caching is working (because docker cache it locally imo):

```
16-alpine: Pulling from library/node
59bf1c3509f3: Already exists 
683dd8c3cc08: Pull complete 
ae5b2724f19b: Pull complete 
39190df3f477: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2c6c59cf4d34d4f937ddfcf33bab9d8bbad8658d1b9de7b97622566a52167f2b
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:16-alpine
docker.io/library/node:16-alpine
latest: Pulling from klmos/test
59bf1c3509f3: Already exists 
683dd8c3cc08: Already exists 
ae5b2724f19b: Already exists 
39190df3f477: Already exists 
a69f3fec5d45: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bd53593d3c15720b49f6228a6e027b8b6b3396edac19683ec5ad5f4ef913b44e
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
[+] Building 0.6s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 131B                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 1.90MB                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:6052ed21a28aff3483d52a6b72ecc3237ce70cfb74f5bc8d467827a16fdf09cc                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/cache_test:latest

16-alpine: Pulling from library/node
Digest: sha256:2c6c59cf4d34d4f937ddfcf33bab9d8bbad8658d1b9de7b97622566a52167f2b
Status: Image is up to date for node:16-alpine
docker.io/library/node:16-alpine
latest: Pulling from klmos/test
Digest: sha256:bd53593d3c15720b49f6228a6e027b8b6b3396edac19683ec5ad5f4ef913b44e
Status: Image is up to date for registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest
[+] Building 0.1s (9/9) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => importing cache manifest from registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 72B                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:6052ed21a28aff3483d52a6b72ecc3237ce70cfb74f5bc8d467827a16fdf09cc                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/cache_test:latest
```

I've checked the two images(pulled from the registry, built locally) in `docker inspect` and it seems like the layer digests are the same.
Image built locally:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:4b6b0dcada8537ff91f11847167d234653f3c3ff1dca9ff509ce2b1961f2a602",
        "RepoTags": [
            "cache_test:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2022-03-06T09:13:05.6932944Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=16.14.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.17",
                "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "node"
            ],
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 112402099,
        "VirtualSize": 112402099,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f310653033bb280f11066e8b4a9103347427a0bf6a1ad9e7ab19df4e006b4852/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9833eb7cfcfb226745a590a8af58952faccabc24cf57a0cb8d66f59e4595e47e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a7a06b5799f10aee38528a75f053d2bff147244c3418fab79c3ecedcc948c32/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f78b9ba5d8999843ff91062118b9b13c8a9fb48e9d787bd1aa542d7cc372d5c2/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:8d3ac3489996423f53d6087c81180006263b79f206d3fdec9e66f0e27ceb8759",
                "sha256:5be440dc5019b5a760b0ebc5c6764cc3759726559486834be386b48dcb09ccdb",
                "sha256:c833154f20e95c1de46899bc89eabd5608ddd1801a173c64efdd19d16603fbc5",
                "sha256:49281578ca1a4cf99861260efa0c9280733e24182e268621525623e69b76f803",
                "sha256:cc3cf0a5db8874be17d0980cb2d0fd1727d8d8d1e3ad9301f3a7e270ad887cb9"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2022-03-06T09:13:16.2790601Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Image pulled from the registry:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:0b69a3739db66e32022e1f58ce1e9f29466b39813569e071f17c08ab1273a090",
        "RepoTags": [
            "registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "registry.gitlab.com/klmos/test@sha256:bd53593d3c15720b49f6228a6e027b8b6b3396edac19683ec5ad5f4ef913b44e"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2022-03-06T08:45:10.5063306Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_VERSION=16.14.0",
                "YARN_VERSION=1.22.17",
                "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "node"
            ],
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 112402099,
        "VirtualSize": 112402099,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f310653033bb280f11066e8b4a9103347427a0bf6a1ad9e7ab19df4e006b4852/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9833eb7cfcfb226745a590a8af58952faccabc24cf57a0cb8d66f59e4595e47e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3a7a06b5799f10aee38528a75f053d2bff147244c3418fab79c3ecedcc948c32/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f78b9ba5d8999843ff91062118b9b13c8a9fb48e9d787bd1aa542d7cc372d5c2/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/493b66cd85249e9bce803d2ec23dc2a019ad3f1c2d9d1f612b4fb1ba1903576d/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:8d3ac3489996423f53d6087c81180006263b79f206d3fdec9e66f0e27ceb8759",
                "sha256:5be440dc5019b5a760b0ebc5c6764cc3759726559486834be386b48dcb09ccdb",
                "sha256:c833154f20e95c1de46899bc89eabd5608ddd1801a173c64efdd19d16603fbc5",
                "sha256:49281578ca1a4cf99861260efa0c9280733e24182e268621525623e69b76f803",
                "sha256:cc3cf0a5db8874be17d0980cb2d0fd1727d8d8d1e3ad9301f3a7e270ad887cb9"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Why docker's --cache-from not working for me? How can I make it working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify how did you build and push your first image, I'm going to assume you didn't specify this --build-arg: `--build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1`

This is what tells Docker to generate the cache manifest that will be stored on the registry, along with the image, and later used for builds who try to use the --cache-from.

Also, --cache-from is a feature that requires the [BuildKit backend](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/#getting-started) to be enabled.

So, your initial `docker build` command should look something like this: `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t cache_test:latest --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 .` and then you push that image to your gitlab registry and finally, you `docker rmi $(docker images -q) -f` followed by a `docker builder prune` to make sure all local images and their respective caches have been cleared.

Once you do all that, build the image using `--cache-from` again and see if it works then.